# putty disconnected error, openssh conflict with putty?

Tags: git, heroku, putty, openssh, pageant

I have been having issues with being able push my changes to my heroku app. I was able to about 1 week ago but not I cannot.

I cant think of anything I did to cause this (possibly installed the heroku toolbelt? to fix another issue, I cant remember now)

Anyway I am total lost and not sure where to turn, I've removed, readded keys , destored keys, created paths for putty and I don't know what else. I could have made it 10x worst for all I know and I have never managed to totally undrestand the whole private,public keys and how putty, pageant, git and heroku work together.

I think I also have Openssh installed and is this possibly conflicting with the other programs (putty, pageant?)

I "think" I have a key set up on heroku. 
I removed all my keys from the site and then in my cmd run

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

this seems to create a key in my

> .ssh

folder called id_rsa and id_rsa.pub

Running

```
heroku keys:add
```

Then seems to add this key to the heroku website. Looking at it will then show this key and also running

```
heroku keys
```

displays;

> ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC...HuBFGI3Q== Steve@STEVE-PC

So I feel I am getting somewhere but now the last this to do is push my code to heroku... running

```
git push heroku master
```

returns a error DIALOG

> PuTTY Fatal Error
>   Disconnected: No support authentication methods available

and in the command window after "ok"ing that message I see

> fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>   Please make sure you have the correct access rights
>   and the repository exists.

What am I missing,

Am I meant to be running a OpenSSH program? 
Should Pageant be running? 
I get a puTTY error, but what is that to do with anything? I thought I was using openssh?
I have totoriseGit installed, does that need some settings or is it conflicting with openssh?
I read about someone creating a system path from putty to openssh, I think i did this at one point but now im not sure and cant even remember how I did this, this sounds more of a hack fix if two programs are conflicting. Is that the case I am having?

This is really starting to stress me out and I was hoping to get this set live last week. So please has anyone ideas what is wrong, or maybe new routes I could go to solve this.

I need a hero to help me with this! thanks

Comment: I do not know heroku, but it lokks to me like that you are setting up private key on the server side, while you should be doing that an client side and put only public key on the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that it was a conflict between Putty and OpenSSH. while creating a key with the heroku command added a key to putty it was using open ssh to try and connect with the git command.

I closed off putty. Opened git GUI. and in the options for OpenSSH I was able to generate a new key. I then manually added this to heroku and everything worked :)